# FluentNhibernate Custom Primary key Automapping - (dis)allow nulls

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, conventions, automapping, convention-over-configur

If this is the way for hard-coded mapping for nullable and not nullable database fields

```
// nullable
Map(x => x.FirstName)
  .Nullable();

// not nullable
Map(x => x.FirstName)
  .Not.Nullable();
```

How is it done with automapping and conventions?

Also, it is not obvious but the purpose that I need it for is to have nhibernate generate insert sql statements without using a primary key field.

Example:
if I want database to generate ProductId, instead of

```
insert into Product (ProductId, Name) values (1, 'product name');
```

NHibernate should generate

```
insert into Product (Name) values ('product name');
```

And, rdbms should not be a question here, as a client code should not care how database assigns it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all, solution is in implementing  IIdConvention interface. I'm adding some code in case someone find this useful.

```
public class PrimaryKeyConvention : IIdConvention
{
    public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
    {            
        instance.Column(instance.EntityType.Name + "Id");
        instance.GeneratedBy.Native();
    }
}
```

It can even be used with custom class for generating id

```
public class PrimaryKeyConvention : FluentNHibernate.Conventions.IIdConvention
{
    public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
    {            
        instance.Column(instance.EntityType.Name + "Id");
        instance.GeneratedBy.Custom(typeof(CustomIdGenerator));
    }
}
public class CustomIdGenerator : NHibernate.Id.IIdentifierGenerator
{

    public object Generate(NHibernate.Engine.ISessionImplementor session, object obj)
    {
        return null; //this should be custom implemented
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the responsability to generate the primary key to database, using fluent nhibernate doesnt solve your problem ?

```
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();

        Map(x => x.Name).Nullable();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't try to explicitly map classes, I would like to use Automapping instead. I tried implementing IKeyPropertyConvention with usage of GeneratedBy.Native() and Nullable(); but it didn't work.  Should I use another interface?

Comment: Correction on the interface I tried to use, I used IIdConvention, not IKeyPropertyConvention.